# Excel VBA - How to Extract the coefficients of approximation polynôm

Tags: excel, vba

I'm coding a statistical program with VBA excel and i have a problem.

I have two columns containing x and f(x) and i want to get the coefficients (a,b, c and d) of the polynôm (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) which approximate the function f.

how can i do that with VBA Code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**3rd Order Polynomial Trendline**

in:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/

Comment: no, it doesnt work !
when i use
a = INDEX(LINEST(B2:B186,A2:A186^{1,2,3}),1)

it gives me syntax error :s

what is the problem here ?